# is it possible to run and quit launch files from code inside a node?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to run a launch file from code inside a node, and to stop one that has launched (as you would in a terminal window)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203154/is-it-possible-to-run-and-quit-launch-files-from-code-inside-a-node?/) by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1504 on 2015-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just noticed this which does what I need

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-20**:
Could you actually run a launch file, or just one node like the example shows?  (or is there an equivalent of rosrun roslaunch roslaunch args...?)  Can you post example code?

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-21**:
I didn't try - I managed to do what I needed as an initial test launching and quiting individual nodes

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if there's a ROS-prescribed way to run a launch file from within another ROS node. As for stopping all the nodes within a launch file, one way to do it is mark at least one of the nodes as required, e.g.,

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbagplay" args="test.bag" required="true"/>
```

If I put this in a launch file, then when `rosbag` exited after the bag file was done playing, all the nodes in that launch file would stop as well.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-01**:
Is it possible to shut down other (from which the given node is **not** being launched) launch files too ?